# Troubleshooting DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, unix, command-line-interface

I am trying to troubleshoot a DNS issue I am currently having with a new project host on an AWS EC2 instance. It is a brand new domain, and I have already updated the nameservers on the registrar side.

It's been a couple days so the new records have propagated. Upon `dig`ging, I have verified the NS records are being correctly pointed to:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> creativealchemyhealing.com in NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32418
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;creativealchemyhealing.com.    IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
creativealchemyhealing.com. 172800 IN   NS  ns-1467.awsdns-55.org.
creativealchemyhealing.com. 172800 IN   NS  ns-364.awsdns-45.com.
creativealchemyhealing.com. 172800 IN   NS  ns-640.awsdns-16.net.
creativealchemyhealing.com. 172800 IN   NS  ns-1551.awsdns-01.co.uk.
```

NS Records Good. So next i went to verify the A record that I set up in the AWS Hosted Zone is querying correctly to the elastic IP of my EC2 instance:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;creativealchemyhealing.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
creativealchemyhealing.com. 300 IN  A   54.183.25.131
```

A Record looks propagated. Excellent.

So then I checked the IP itself to see if that loaded... IP address loads fine: 54.183.25.131.

So why then does the actual domain not query properly? www.creativealchemyhealing.com

What am I missing? Is there a more effective solution to troubleshoot DNS issues other than using the `dig` utility?

Comment: Can you include dig output for the name you say that you have problems with (`www.creativealchemyhealing.com`)? The `+trace +add` options may be helpful in case something is actually wrong with the delegation.

Comment: +1 for this question from me, for **not redacting the domain name**.  Made solving the problem easy, instead of a punishing series of *how-about* questions.  Thanks, Robert.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I'm interested in learning more about how to better troubleshoot an issue like this in the future, so I was playing with the `dig` options you suggested, but I am unable to identify the syntax for using them. After looking through the help manual on `dig` it appeared I should use the following syntax: `dig www.creativealchemyhealing.com in NS +trace`, however its producing no output. Nor is `+add` option, and I can't even find that one in the `man` page. I've tried about 20 other syntax forms and none of them produce output either. Can you suggest the syntax you would use?

Comment: in linux I can write `dig www.creativealchemyhealing.com +trace +add` (ubuntu), what platform are you on?

Comment: @Sverre Ubuntu as well. I tried that one actually: 

`; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> www.creativealchemyhealing.com +trace +add
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 2 ms`

Comment: @McWayWeb It may be that the configured resolver does not want to serve the list of root nameservers needed for the very first step in `+trace`. Try eg `dig +trace +add @8.8.8.8 www.creativealchemyhealing.com` and see if `+trace` works as intended then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.creativealchemyhealing.com` is not the same as `creativealchemyhealing.com`

you need another A record for that one, or a cname

for example

```
www.creativealchemyhealing.com. 300 IN  A   54.183.25.131
```